# How can i set the ion-item in right?

Tags: css

I want to align ion-item in right position.I used **align:right** but its not working.
Here is my code.

```
<ion-item text-wrap style="width:50%;align:right;" >   
  <p style="font-size:10px;color:#C2BEC1;"> {{list.TAG_FROM}} {{list.TAG_DT}}</p>
  <p style="color: #2F2D30;font-size:15px;"> {{list.TAG}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **text-align: right;**

```
<ion-item text-wrap style="width:50%;text-align: right;" >
  <p style="font-size:10px;color:#C2BEC1;"> {{list.TAG_FROM}} {{list.TAG_DT}}</p>
  <p style="color: #2F2D30;font-size:15px;"> {{list.TAG}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-item text-wrap style="width:50%;float: right;" >

        <p style="font-size:10px;color:#C2BEC1;"> {{list.TAG_FROM}} {{list.TAG_DT}}</p>
        <p style="color: #2F2D30;font-size:15px;"> {{list.TAG}}</p>


  </ion-item>
```